# Qt or j2me is better?

Tags: qt, java-me, nokia

I am planning to do some development for Nokia Devices. Can someone tell me which to use between Qt framework and j2me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt applications are platform native and you can do *almost* whatever you want. Qt is mainly C++.

J2ME development on the other hand is Java based and yields byte code binaries that are limited by the Java virtual machine running on the phone.

If you can do C++/Qt go for it

Comment: Thanks mmonem. Are there any features that j2me can not do and qt can do?

Comment: Not features exactly. Qt = more close to the platform = more control = more effort, unfortunately.

Comment: Qt actually does a good job at choosing sane defaults and reducing need for complex configuration. And for a C++-framework, it has some amazing magic.

Comment: @mmonem: Great and succinct explanation. :)

Comment: @delnan: what is the "defaults" you are referring to? And how does it reduce the complex configuration? Thanks

Comment: @Krishnan: Most widgets do what you would expect from a good GUI (scrollbars if and only if needed, widgets resize as the window resizes (if you use such a layout), text editors support all the usual shortcuts, etc) "out of the box". Contrast this with certain GUI toolkits that e.g. require the same 6 ugly lines every time you want a scrollbar... and that scrollbar is persistent.

Answer (score 2):

Well, defenetly j2me will work on more Nokia devices, including some low-grade cell-phones.

Qt will give you the ability to write richer & more useful UI which is closer to the OS. This is especially important on Symbian & Maemo-based devices.

Needless to say, Qt would take way more time to develop and compile for different Nokia platforms.

Comment: Thanks BarsMonster. My idea was that , if I develop an j2me app, I can targets devices even beyond the Nokia devices. Is it possible and would there be any hindrances to my initiative?

Comment: Just compare UI of j2me app and awesome Qt ones. Qt is just WAY better and nicer to use. j2me works everywhere but slower, have kinda terrible UI & have many j2me-related imits.

Comment: Hi BarsMonster, could you provide any specific j2me-related limits?

Comment: J2ME UI can be really improved if you use something like LWUIT, modern phones are really good